# Can't kill process, not in zombie or uninterruptable sleep

Tags: linux, kill

I can't figure out how to kill this process.  I ran `du`, but it took too long so I tried to kill it.  It didn't die.  I've tried SIGKILL, SIGSTOP, SIGINT, etc, with no effect (can't kill it, can't stop it).  It is **not** in `D` or `Z` state, as you can see in the following `top` output:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                         
12047 alex      39  19  5656  496  408 R  99.6  0.0 209:10.04 du --max-depth=1 -h
```

Since it won't stop, I can't attach to it with gdb either.

Does anyone have any ideas how to kill this without rebooting?

Comment: Give us the output of `ps -l -p 12047` - specifically the value of the WCHAN column.  My guess is the process is in "disk wait", which makes it unkillable.

Comment: I've gone and rebooted, but I used a similar command before I did so, and the WCHAN column only had -.  Disk wait would put it in `D` state, and not result in high CPU, wouldn't it?

Comment: If it doesn't stop, and wchan is empty, this likely means forever cycle in kernel code. You should study kernel debugging for this. Useful variants are external debugger (commands are sent from another machone) and tracing hooks.

Comment: Is this by any chance done on a `sshfs` mount?

Comment: sshfs mount, or ANY mount... does the command cross filesystems?

Comment: The directory in which I ran the command contains a couple of symlinks to directories on another fs.  Both filesystems are local and ext3.  Do you think that would have an effect?

Comment: I have no idea if it's related or not, but this was running on kernel 3.2.0-3-rt-amd64 from Debian unstable

Comment: @lxop can you reproduce this?

Comment: @lxop I'm calling too localized, hit up a mod if you can reproduce and need this reopened.

Answer (score -3):

Try using `killall -9 (name of process)`

Comment: Signal 9 is SIGKILL, which he said he already tried