# Kill a stuck process in running state

Tags: kill, process-management

I am trying to kill a `du -mh` command that has been stuck running for 18 hours. I have tried many kill signals `kill -15`, `kill -2`, `kill -9` as root but with no luck. Are there any other techniques to kill this process?

Note this is in `R` running state, yet it does not appear to be responding to my kill signals.

[image: Screenshot of top command]

```
 ps -Z 31806
 LABEL                             PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 unconfined                      31806 ?        RN   1137:41 du
```

Comment: You can't kill a zombie, it's already dead. I have no idea what those many SE answers are talking about. You're probably rather thinking of processes stuck in an uninterruptible sleep (`D`, not `R` state). In your case: maybe you don't have permission to kill it? Try `strace -e trace=kill kill PID`, and if that shows that the kill() is successful, attach to the `df` process with `strace -p PID`, kill it and see how it's reacting to the signal.

Comment: @mosvy `strace -e trace=kill kill PID` returns exit code 0, and `strace -p PID` shows attached, but no output following `kill`, `kill -9` command

Comment: @mosvy you're right, I've removed the mention of zombie state from my question.

Comment: will `kill -TSTP PID` stop it?

Comment: A process can not catch a SIGKILL (signal 9) so if it doesn't help trying to send that, I can't see other possibilities than you not being allowed to send signals to the process at all. As the top output shows that it's owned by root, you need to be root to send it signals.

Comment: @Henrik I am sending signals as root`
@mosvy `kill -TSTP PID` doesn't stop it either.

Comment: Could you attach to it with `gdb -p PID`? Anyways, please add the output of `ps -Z PID` (instead of the `top` screenshot, which may not be accessible to some people). Also mention if you're using any kind of virtualization/containerization.

Comment: The last output of `gdb -p PID` is "Attaching to process 31806"

Comment: Which means that it cannot attach it (`strace` succeeds because it uses `PTRACE_SEIZE` which doesn't stop the process). This may be some kind of kernel bug -- also see this old [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43035/cant-kill-process-not-in-zombie-or-uninterruptable-sleep).

Comment: @mosvy I think you're right, that this is some kernel bug. Will restart the server later to resolve. Thank you

Comment: Server restarted, a soft shutdown was stuck too. As this was an AWS instance, I had to stop the instance and start it back up again. Problem resolved, assumed kernel loop / bug.

Comment: do/did you have any NFS mounts on that VM?  If so, see `nfs(5)` and read the info on the `soft` and `hard` mount options (which control timeout & retry behaviour, effectively giving you a choice between hangs like this or the risk of data corruption).   I ask because I've seen hangs on df or du many times over the years when an NFS server doesn't respond to an NFS client.

Comment: @cas I have no NFS mounts, but I think the `du` hang may be related to docker containers hosted on this server.

Answer (score -2):

You could use :

```
kill -kill PID
```

This is very common command for force kill PID.

Comment: short / friendly name for `kill -9 PID` which I have already tried